# Are pipe reads not greater than PIPE_BUF atomic?

Tags: linux, pipe, concurrency

The GNU C library manual briefly mentioned that both reads and writes for a pipe are [atomic](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html)

> Reading or writing pipe data is atomic if the size of data written is not greater than PIPE_BUF.

However, the manual pages on Linux, like [man 7 pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe), do not mentioned that reads are atomic and [man 2 read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) explicitly states that read may return less than the requested amount if read was interrupted by a signal.

So are the read calls for a pipe with the read length under `PIPE_BUF` are truly atomic on Linux?

In particular, if a single writer to the pipe always write, for example, 12 byte chunk and there are 2 concurrent readers for the pipe that read the pipe by 12 bytes, do those readers either get exactly 12 byte read or an error like `EAGAIN` with no possibility of getting a partial read?

Also, what about the case when the writer writes by 12 byte chunks but concurrent readers try to read up to `PIPE_BUF/12` chunks at once? Does a successful read then always return the exact multiplier of 12 bytes or can it return any number of bytes?

Comment: The link you shared also says : `Reading or writing a larger amount of data may not be atomic; for example, output data from other processes sharing the descriptor may be interspersed. Also, once PIPE_BUF characters have been written, further writes will block until some characters are read.`

Comment: @schaiba This is not my case as all my reads and writes will be below PIPE_BUF and the multiple of the same chunk size (12 bytes) and I need to know if I can assume on Linux that the read call will never see a read of a partial chunk.

Comment: If you're sure you'll stay below PIPE_BUF then you should be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the implementation of `pipe_read` in `source/fs/pipe.c` has changed quite a bit in the Linux kernel, but from a quick reading of the code in [2.0.40](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=2.0.40#L30), [2.4.37](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=2.4.37#L40), [2.6.32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=2.6.32#L329), [3.11](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=3.11#L372) and [4.9](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c?v=4.9#L249), it seems to me that whenever there has been (or is, while `read` is blocking) a write of size *w* and a read of size *r* with *r* > *w* then `read` will return at least *w* bytes. So if you have fixed-size chunks (of a size smaller than `PIPE_BUF`) and always make reads of that same size, then you are in practice guaranteed to always read a whole chunk.

On the other hand, if you have variable-sized chunks, then you have no such guarantee. There is a guarantee of atomicity only on the write side: a write of less than `PIPE_BUF` will not be cut by another writer. But on the reader side, if there have been e.g. a write of 10 bytes followed by a write of 20 bytes, and you later try to read 15 bytes, then you'll get the complete first write and the first 5 bytes of the second write. The `read` call doesn't stop reading data until it would have to block or its output buffer is full.

If you want to transmit data in chunks, use a [datagram socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_socket) instead of a pipe.

Comment: In my case I have measurements data that are sent to the receiver in small fixed-sized packets (12 bytes). When for some reason the receiver cannot keep up with the sender and the pipe becomes full, the sender discards the oldest packets. This is fine as those are obsolete at that moment. And for that the sender reads from the pipe discarding what it has wrote before. But that requires that concurrent reads are atomic and Linux provides that :). With datagrams I cannot do this read-to-discard without rather complex SO_REUSEPORT code. Besides, with the pipe I can read several packets at once.